# Loop through an anonymous array inside perl hash

Tags: perl, loops, hashmap

**Background**: I am new to Perl and I am tinkering with a simple script that loops through a hash value that is an anonymous array.

**The Issue** I cannot seem to loop through the array. All I get is `ARRAY(0x1663b78)`

**The Code**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
package Foo;
use strict "vars";

sub new {
    my $class = shift;
    my $self = {
        distro  => "",
        pkg_mgr => "",
        options => ["PHP + Apache", "PHP + Lighthttpd", "PHP + Nginx", "RubyGems + Rails", "Node JS + NPM"]
    };

    bless $self, $class;

    return $self;
}

sub print_options {
    my($self) = @_;
    foreach($self->{options}) {
        print $_ . "\n";
    }
}

my $setup = new Foo();
$setup->print_options();
```

Also, if someone could kindly inform me if it's remotely useful to use `use strict "vars";` if I really have no need for private or public variables. I know how I would do this in PHP but I can't wrap my head around this in Perl.

Lastly, my reason for using Perl is because eventually I'm going to make an application that installs software for servers (including PHP). This script will require user interaction via command line.

Comment: You should just do `use strict;` - there is no reason to do `use strict "vars";` which only turns on some strictures.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A few little Perl clues:

- Use [Data::Dumper](http://perldoc.perl.org/Data/Dumper.html) whenever you have problems like this. `Data::Dumper` will help you understand the structure.
- If you're going to go all object oriented, go full bore. You have constructors and methods. Methods should return values, and you operate on those values. Each method and constructor should be as independent as possible and have little knowledge of your overall object structure.
- Operate in the `main` package. You should flip your program around. The last two statements should be on the top, and define your package below.

If you used `Data::Dumper` and dumped the data of `$self` when you called it, you would realize that `$self` is a hash with three keys, and that the `options` key is pointing to an anonymous array.

In order to do what you want, you have to *dereference* that anonymous array:

```
sub print_options {
    my($self) = @_;
    for ( @{$self->{options} } ) {
        print $_ . "\n";
    }
}
```

However, let's clean up your program to make it a complete class. First, methods never print -- they return values. Thus, you should not have a `print_options` method. Instead, it should return the array (or a reference to an array).

Also, your constructor doesn't have to know how your `Options` are structured. What if you change it? Let's look at a changed program:

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl
#
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw(say);

my $setup = Foo->new;
for my $option ( $setup->Option ) {
    say $option;
}

package Foo;

sub new {
    my $class = shift;
    my $self = {};
    bless $self, $class;
    $self->Option("PHP + Apache");
    $self->Option("PHP + Lighthttpd");
    $self->Option("PHP + Nginx");
    $self->Option("RubyGems + Rails");
    $self->Option("Node JS + NPM");
    return $self;
}

sub Distro {
    my $self   = shift;
    my $distro = shift;
    if ( defined $distro ) {
        $self->{DISTRO} = $distro;
    }
    return $self->{DISTRO};
}

sub Package_Manager {
    my $self    = shift;
    my $package = shift;
    if ( defined $package ) {
        $self->{PACKAGE} = $package;
    }
    return $self->{PACKAGE};
}

sub Option {
    my $self = shift;
    my $option = shift;;

    if ( not exists $self->{OPTION} ) {
        $self->{OPTION} = [];
    }

    if ( defined $option ) {
        push @{ $self->{OPTION} }, $option;
    }
    my @array = @{ $self->{OPTION} };
    return wantarray ? @array : \@array;
}
```

First, unlike PHP, Perl *compiles* the code before execution. Thus, you can define packages and their subroutine on the bottom of the program. The few lines of code above operation in the default *main* package. If I did use a package variable in my `Foo` package, I wouldn't accidentally  be using it in my program.

Notice that none of my methods or my constructor know about the structure of the `Foo` object. When I set my options in my `new` constructor, I call my `Option` method to do the setting. This way, if I change the way I store my options, I only have to change my `Option` method and not worry where else in my package it has to be changed. It also simplifies my program and makes it easier to support.

By making my `Option` method to either set or get my options, I simplify the code. I can see that I'm storing options in an anonymous array, and it's obvious that I need to *dereference* it when I return the object. I like using `wantarray` and giving the user the option whether they want an array or a reference to an array.

Notice that I don't simply return `$self->{OPTION}`. It is a reference to an array and should have worked, but if I return that, I'm returning the memory location of that object! Thus, if a user changes that reference, they're changing my object ***without going through my methods***. Thus, I make another array, and return a reference to that. Muck with that array reference all you want, you're not changing my object.

This code isn't complete. I can set options, but not unset options. It may be nice to have a way to *push* and *pop* options. Instead, all you can do at this point is return the entire list, and not modify it.

Comment: +1 for clarity and doc reference. Two more questions: Why deference the array? What does that do? Also, Perl OOP is a little more abstract than what I'm used to with PHP so how exactly do you mean "go full bore"? In PHP I would follow this process: [http://pastebin.com/iZ1gUfAm](http://pastebin.com/iZ1gUfAm)

Comment: @djthoms A reference is just the memory location of an object. For example, my `$self->{OPTION}` merely points to the memory location where I stored my array. Thus the `ARRAY(0x1663b78)` says you're storing an array at memory location `0x1663b78`. What you want isn't the memory location, but the array at that memory location. A _reference_ takes an array and gives you a location in memory. A **de**reference takes the memory location and returns the array.

Comment: @djthoms I added to my answer how the package `Foo` should be written as a _full bore_ package. My methods return values and not print them. That's for my program to do. My various pieces of my class have limited knowledge of the entire structure of my class. My constructor doesn't know how I store options. My Option method doesn't know how I store the Distro. Keeping everythign separate and with a single purpose makes writing classes cleaner and easier to maintain.

Comment: @djthoms Perl objects don't have true private methods. There's a community agreement that you don't use non-documented methods and you don't operate directly on the structure much like there's an agreed upon social contract that you don't peek into open windows because someone forgot to pull the blinds. Usually, it is understand that if something begins with an underscore, it's private. However, you should use [POD](perldoc.perl.org/perlpod.html) to document your class. Then,  if something isn't documented. It's private.

Comment: This is an truly awesome answer. My only criticism is that `$self->{OPTION} = [] unless exists $self->{OPTION}` is superfluous, thanks to autovivification.

Comment: Very verbose answer! Perl is definitely a learning curve from other scripting languages. Thanks for all of this very useful info!

Answer (score 4):

`$self->{options}` is not an array but a *reference* to an array. You need to de-reference it to be able to iterate through its values.

```
my @options = @{ $self=>{options} };
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to do the below change.

```
foreach(@{$self->{options}}) {
        ^^                ^
```

`options` is the key to an `arrayref` and you need to de-reference it to use it.

As to your other question, a more general pair of pragmas are recommended, especially for beginners

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```